# Finding all integers under v which are the sum of two abundant numbers

Tags: python

Write a function that returns a list of all the positive integers under v that can be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers.

I'm very new to coding so it's quite messy and I don't even understand how half of it works. I tried multiple things, all on the premise of, I will add the 0th element with the 0th, then the 1st, then the second, until I'm adding the 0th element with the last. Then the 0th element changes to the 1st and I'm adding it to the 1st element, then the 2nd element, then the third until I'm adding the 1st element and the last.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
def divisors(a):
    b=[]
    for i in range(1,a):
        if a%i==0:
            b.append(i)
    if sum(b)>a:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

```
def abundantNums(n):
    list1=[]
    for i in range(1,n):
        if divisors(i):
            list1.append(i)
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    return(list1)
```

```
def AbundantSums(v):
    answers=[]
    x=0
    h=0 
    list1=[]
    for i in range(1,v):
        if divisors(i):
            list1.append(i)
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    l=len(list1)
    for k in range(1,l+1):
        if list1[x]+list1[h]<=v:
            answers.append(list1[x]+list1[h])
            h+=1 
    print(answers)
```

Comment: Would you give some example of in/outputs?  to make it clear.

Comment: @DanielHao, the OP isn't asking for the first "n" abundant numbers, they're asking for the all integers less than "v" that can be expressed in at least one way as the sum of two abundant numbers... Not all the numbers that can be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers will also be abundant. if v == 100, the function AbundantSums should return 34 numbers: `[24, 30, 32, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98]`

Comment: I guess I can assume *that* but just want OP to confirm.  Just try to understand the requirement first.... because OP mention that -Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a sequence of functions that'll give you what you're after:

```
def divisors(a: int) -> list:
    """
    Returns a list of all the proper divisors of "a". 
    """
    b=[]
    for i in range(1,a):
    
        if a%i==0:
            b.append(i)
    return b

def is_abundant(n: int) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True if all proper divisors of "n" add up to a value greater than "n", else False.
    """
    return sum(divisors(n)) > n

def is_sum_of_two_abundant_nums(n: int) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True if "n" can be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers, else False.
    """
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        if is_abundant(i) and is_abundant(n-i):
            return True
    return False

def AbundantSums(v: int) -> list:
    """
    Returns a list of all numbers less than "v" that can be expressed as the sum
    of two abundant numbers.
    """
    answers = []
    for i in range(1, v):
        if is_sum_of_two_abundant_nums(i):
            answers.append(i)
    return answers


# Examples of AbundantSums implemented:
    
print (AbundantSums(25))
# Result: 
#     [24]

print (AbundantSums(40))
# Result:
#     [24, 30, 32, 36, 38]

print (AbundantSums(70))
# Result:
    # [24, 30, 32, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68]
```

Does this help?

Comment: If you're feeling ever so kind, I do have one more problem. I need to compute the sum of all the positive integers less than 30,000 that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers.

Comment: @alex I suggest you post it as a new question, describing clearly what form your inputs will take, exactly what output you expect, and then a sample of the code you've tried, highlighting where you've run into trouble. That'll give you the best probability of getting a helpful answer here. Cheers